# JQuery UI two datepickers with from and to fields. Disable 5 days from selected date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using two date pickers (From and To). Based on a condition I want to disable 5 days in 2nd `datepicker(To)` after selecting a date in 1st `datepicker(from)`.

I tried the following codes...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pkg = "<?php echo $package ?>";
      $(function() {


        if(pkg=="Ordinary"){
            var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
          from = $("#date")
            .datepicker({
              defaultDate: "+1w",
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              minDate: 0

            })
            .on("change", function() {
              var fdate = getDate(this);
              to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this)+5);
            }),
          to = $("#delivery_date")
            .datepicker({
               defaultDate: "+1w",
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              minDate: 0
            })
            .on("change", function() {
              from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
            });

        }

 function getDate(element) {
          var date;
          try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
          } catch (error) {
            date = null;
          }

          return date;
        }
      });

</script>
```

But this code disabling all the date before Jan, 2027.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it this way -

```
enter code here

function getDate(element) {
          var date;
          if(pkg=="Ordinary"){
            try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
          } catch (error) {
            date = null;
          }
          return date;
        }
```